# android not registering action down on a second pointer

Tags: java, android

So I am currently creating a simple paint app partly for a school project and partly because it's way to much fun and i'm trying to make sure I get all the touch events by reading through the history that was working until today when I attempted to add multi-touch, now drawing with one finger is fine but when you start using a another one the Action_Down is not run for it causing a random line to be drawn. Here is my code:

```
package com.sciguy.paint;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;


public class DrawingView extends View {

    private Paint drawPaint;

    private static Canvas drawCanvas;

    private List<Point> points = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private List<Point> oldPoints = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
        drawPaint.setColor(CommonResources.getColor());
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(CommonResources.size);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        if (CommonResources.oldThread == null) {
            CommonResources.oldThread = DrawBitmap;
            DrawBitmap.start();
        } else {
            CommonResources.stopThread = true;
            //noinspection SynchronizeOnNonFinalField
            synchronized (CommonResources.oldThread) {
                CommonResources.oldThread.notify();
            }
            //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
            while (CommonResources.stopThread) ;
            CommonResources.oldThread = DrawBitmap;
            DrawBitmap.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (CommonResources.canvasBitmap == null) {
            CommonResources.canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(CommonResources.canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(CommonResources.canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float curX = event.getX();
        float curY = event.getY();
        if (CommonResources.fill) {
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (!CommonResources.isFillThreadRunning) {
                    new FloodFillThread(ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Flood Fill", "Filling Area..."), handler, CommonResources.canvasBitmap, new android.graphics.Point((int) curX, (int) curY), CommonResources.canvasBitmap.getPixel((int) curX, (int) curY), CommonResources.getColor()).start();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            Point point;
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                point = new Point();
                curX = event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
                curY = event.getY(event.getActionIndex());
                point.oldX = curX;
                point.oldY = curY;
                addOldPoint(curX, curY, event.getActionIndex());
            } else {
                for (int h = 0; h < event.getHistorySize(); h++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                        curX = event.getHistoricalX(i, h);
                        curY = event.getHistoricalY(i, h);
                        point = getOldPoint(i);
                        point.newX = curX;
                        point.newY = curY;
                        addOldPoint(curX, curY, i);
                        points.add(point);
                        updateBitmap();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void clearScreen() {
        CommonResources.canvasBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    public void updateBitmap() {
        synchronized (DrawBitmap) {
            DrawBitmap.notify();
        }
    }

    final Thread DrawBitmap = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!CommonResources.stopThread) {
                for (Point p : points) {
                    drawCanvas.drawLine(p.oldX, p.oldY, p.newX, p.newY, drawPaint);
                    points.remove(p);
                    postInvalidate();
                }
                try {
                    synchronized (DrawBitmap) {
                        DrawBitmap.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            CommonResources.stopThread = false;
        }
    });

    private class Point {
        float newX, newY, oldX, oldY;
        int id;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return newX + ", " + newY + ", " + oldX + ", " + oldY;
        }
    }

    private void addOldPoint(float x, float y, int id) {
        for (Point p : oldPoints) {
            if (p.id == id) {
                oldPoints.remove(p);
            }
        }
        Point p = new Point();
        p.oldX = x;
        p.oldY = y;
        p.id = id;
        oldPoints.add(p);
    }

    private Point getOldPoint(int id) {
        for (Point p : oldPoints) {
            if (p.id == id) {
                return p;
            }
        }

        return new Point();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                postInvalidate();
            }
        }
    };

    public static void updateCanvas() {
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(CommonResources.canvasBitmap);
    }

}
```

This is the code for the view and it's mostly self explanatory however here's a few things anyway. CommonResources is a simple class that holds some global variables that need to be preserved between activity swaps (The bitmap, the paint color, etc). A thread is used to draw to the bitmap to save time on the ondraw method. and there is a fill function that is currently working however for the sake of this issue please ignore any reference to it (It's in another class anyway). If any more code or clarification is needed I would be happy to provide it.

Thanks, Sciguy

Answer (score 0):

Well I just figured it out here's the updated code:

```
package com.sciguy.paint;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;


public class DrawingView extends View {

    private Paint drawPaint;

    private static Canvas drawCanvas;

    private List<Point> points = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private List<Point> oldPoints = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
        drawPaint.setColor(CommonResources.getColor());
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(CommonResources.size);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        if (CommonResources.oldThread == null) {
            CommonResources.oldThread = DrawBitmap;
            DrawBitmap.start();
        } else {
            CommonResources.stopThread = true;
            //noinspection SynchronizeOnNonFinalField
            synchronized (CommonResources.oldThread) {
                CommonResources.oldThread.notify();
            }
            //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
            while (CommonResources.stopThread) ;
            CommonResources.oldThread = DrawBitmap;
            DrawBitmap.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (CommonResources.canvasBitmap == null) {
            CommonResources.canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(CommonResources.canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(CommonResources.canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float curX = event.getX();
        float curY = event.getY();
        if (CommonResources.fill) {
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (!CommonResources.isFillThreadRunning) {
                    new FloodFillThread(ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Flood Fill", "Filling Area..."), handler, CommonResources.canvasBitmap, new android.graphics.Point((int) curX, (int) curY), CommonResources.canvasBitmap.getPixel((int) curX, (int) curY), CommonResources.getColor()).start();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            Point point;
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    point = new Point();
                    curX = event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
                    curY = event.getY(event.getActionIndex());
                    point.oldX = curX;
                    point.oldY = curY;
                    addOldPoint(curX, curY, event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()));

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    for (int h = 0; h < event.getHistorySize(); h++) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                            curX = event.getHistoricalX(i, h);
                            curY = event.getHistoricalY(i, h);
                            point = getOldPoint(event.getPointerId(i));
                            point.newX = curX;
                            point.newY = curY;
                            addOldPoint(curX, curY, event.getPointerId(i));
                            points.add(point);
                            updateBitmap();
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    curX = event.getX(event.getActionIndex());
                    curY = event.getY(event.getActionIndex());
                    point = getOldPoint(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()));
                    point.newX = curX;
                    point.newY = curY;
                    points.add(point);
                    updateBitmap();

                    break;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }



    public static void clearScreen() {
        CommonResources.canvasBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    public void updateBitmap() {
        synchronized (DrawBitmap) {
            DrawBitmap.notify();
        }
    }

    final Thread DrawBitmap = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!CommonResources.stopThread) {
                for (Point p : points) {
                    drawCanvas.drawLine(p.oldX, p.oldY, p.newX, p.newY, drawPaint);
                    points.remove(p);
                    postInvalidate();
                }
                try {
                    synchronized (DrawBitmap) {
                        DrawBitmap.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            CommonResources.stopThread = false;
        }
    });

    private class Point {
        float newX, newY, oldX, oldY;
        int id;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return newX + ", " + newY + ", " + oldX + ", " + oldY;
        }
    }

    private void addOldPoint(float x, float y, int id) {
        for (Point p : oldPoints) {
            if (p.id == id) {
                oldPoints.remove(p);
            }
        }
        Point p = new Point();
        p.oldX = x;
        p.oldY = y;
        p.id = id;
        oldPoints.add(p);
    }

    private Point getOldPoint(int id) {
        for (Point p : oldPoints) {
            if (p.id == id) {
                return p;
            }
        }

        return new Point();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                postInvalidate();
            }
        }
    };

    public static void updateCanvas() {
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(CommonResources.canvasBitmap);
    }

}
```

Changes:

I Added a switch case (This was there but for debugging case it had been removed), I used both MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP (And there down variants respectively) this alone both fixed a caused a problem, now all the Action_up's and Downs were being called however the pointer ids were being set to the lowest possible number, Ie if P1 = 0, and P2 = 1 then when pointer P1 is removed P2 becomes 0 witch was causing a unnecessary line to be drawn from the last know position of the first pointer to the current position of the second one. So to fix this instead of using event.getActionIndex for saving to oldPoints I used event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) witch returned a unique id and fixed my last problem.

Thanks to all who looked a my problem, I know 17 did :)
If in the future you need any clarification feel free to ask

-Sciguy